# Qual é o valor padrão da velocidade nas animações do Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Quero rolar a tela até o elemento com ID `main-title`, para isto estou usando a função de animação do jQuery com 1000 ms conforme abaixo:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#main-title").scrollTop()}, 1000);
```

Entretanto este não parece o mesmo valor das outras animações que o Bootstrap faz em seus componentes. Gostaria de usar o mesmo valor padrão que o Bootstrap 4 usa para fazer suas animações em geral.

Existe um valor padrão do Bootstrap para a função `animate`? Se existe, qual é este valor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme o source em SCSS do bootstrap https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss parece que são estes:

```
$transition-base:             all .2s ease-in-out !default;
$transition-fade:             opacity .15s linear !default;
$transition-collapse:         height .35s ease !default;
```

Transição padrão `$transition-base` que serve para aqueles elementos que tem diferentes mudanças no CSS é de 200ms (0.2s).

Transição de mudança de opacidade (transparência) `$transition-fade` que serve para aqueles elementos que são ocultados ou exibidos é de 150ms (0.15s).

Transição de mudança de altura (para ocultar menus) `$transition-collapse`  é de 350ms (0.35s).

Mas vale notar que o efeito de `$transition-base` é em `ease-in-out` e o `$transition-collapse` é em `ease`, o unico linear é o `$transition-base`, todas animações básicas no jQuery são lineares, a não ser que use jQueryUI, que lhe proporciona usar as variações.

---

Exemplo da variação dos efeitos:

```css
.exemplo {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px #ccc solid;
    height: 35px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.exemplo .teste {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #f00;
}

.linear {
    animation: EaseAnimate 1.5s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}
.ease {
    animation: EaseAnimate 1.5s ease 0s infinite alternate;
}
.ease-in-out {
    animation: EaseAnimate 1.5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes EaseAnimate
{
  0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
      transform: translateX(465px);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Linear:</p>
<div class="exemplo">
    <div class="teste linear"></div>
</div>

<p>Ease:</p>
<div class="exemplo">
    <div class="teste ease"></div>
</div>

<p>Ease-in-out:</p>
<div class="exemplo">
    <div class="teste ease-in-out"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Resposta completíssima!